# Making the orthonormal set with a given function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, orthonormal

I have a question about the orthonormal set.

Let $f\in \mathcal{L}^2(\mu)$ (i.e. $f$ is measurable and $\int_X|f|^2d\mu<\infty$) on a measurable space $X$ such that $\Vert f \Vert=1$ be given. ($\Vert \cdot \Vert$ denotes inner product.)

I wonder whether I can make the orthonormal set with that given $f$.

I thought I could. My approach is this: For some orthonormal set {$\phi_n$} with a countable basis where $\phi_n\in\mathcal{L}^2(\mu)$, I can make approximation by
$$
f\sim\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n\phi_n
$$
where $c_n=\int_Xf\bar{\phi_n}d\mu$.

Then I may replace $\phi_1$ with $f$, $\phi_2$ with some function made up with $\phi_2, \phi_3, \cdots$, say $g$, such that $(f,g)=0$, $\phi_3$ with some function made up with $\phi_3, \phi_4, \cdots$, say $h$, such that $(f,h)=(g,h)=0$, and so on.

By iterating the fashion above, I thought that I could finally get what I want... but I'm not sure.

Is my approach right?

Comment: What happens if $X$ is not separable?

Comment: @JackyChong Sorry, I don't know what happens because I am a beginner yet. Could you explain it to me?

Comment: I am not sure whether you will have a countable orthogonal basis.

Comment: @JackyChong Oops, I have a countable basis. Let me edit my question.

Comment: it seems that you are looking to the Gram-Schmidt process applied to polynomials

Comment: @GCab Can I apply the Gram-Schmidt process to functions which are not polynomial?

Comment: I am not a theorist .. but once you have the inner product defined and the functions are in ${\mathcal L}^2$ you can always deduct the inner product from one of two functions and leave the other normal, and so on in cascade

Comment: @GCab Thank you for your advice.